# Verbose preference as argument with space

Tags: powershell

I have a case where parameters and their values are stored in a database and passed into a `workflow` separated by a space. Like this:

```
Foo-Bar -hostName contoso -ipAddress 127.0.0.1 -userPassword passw0rd
```

I'm now trying to set verbose preference *true* using this format, but this errors:

```
Foo-Bar -hostName contoso -ipAddress 127.0.0.1 -userPassword passw0rd -Verbose $true
```

The correct format is of course `-Verbose:$true` but the value must be separated by a *space* for my use-case. I've also tried `-Verbose '$:true'` but this does not work.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use splatting? Pass your parameters to the splat, $param2 is separated by a space now.

```
function Test ([string]$name, [switch]$switch){
    if($switch){
        write-host "$name the switch is on"
    } else {
        write-host "$name the switch is off"
    }
}

$param1 = 'steve'
$param2 = $false

$splat = @{ 'name' = $param1;  'switch' = $param2; }

Test @splat
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.

Simple as that.
Switch parameter expect the parameter to be defined either with the parameter name only or using the `:` to set the value.

However, what you could do.

If your workflow can accept to pass nothing as a parameter (not null, not an empty string, not 0, just... nothing or a space, you can use the switch parameter normally `Foo-Bar -verbose`

Otherwise, you could add a function parameter with a boolean type and set the verbose action preference yourself.

```
 If ($EnableVerbose) {$VerbosePreference =  [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Continue}
```

Here's as simple example in action.

```
function Foo-Bar() {

[cmdletbinding()] 
 Param([string]$File,[Boolean]$EnableVerbose)


If ($EnableVerbose) {$VerbosePreference =  [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Continue}
   Write-Verbose 'Hi, My name is Samantha. I grew up in a small city in the north of Carolina. At age 5, I was expert at finding my way back to home after daddy left me alone in the wood. At that age, it happened several time already. It wasn''t the first time he did that to me and it wouldn''t be the last !...'
}

Foo-Bar -File 'MyFile.ext' -EnableVerbose $true
```